# how to fix Screen('OpenMovie'.. leading to Matlab crash

Tags: matlab, visualization, gstreamer, ati, psychtoolbox

Setup: Matlab Student 2014, Psychtoolbox 3.0.12, GStreamer 1.4.3, ATI Radeon 69xx, all on Windows 7, **all 64bit**.

Screen works with different arguments, only at `Screen('OpenMovie'` the whole Program (Matlab) crashes - sometimes with Error (unable to synchronize framerate), sometimes no error at all.

I know it is quite specific and I think it is somehow in my configuration (the code will work on a different system (lab)).

What I've tried so far:

- Psychtoolbox 3.0.11, GStreamer SDK, GStreamer 1.4.1
- renewed ATI drivers (complete catalyst control center,..)
- removed multi-monitor setting (makes it harder to debug then..)
- Matlab itself works, GStreamer too (tried playing movie with playbin)
- anything SyncTrouble states: wait for vertical synch, triple buffering off
- overriding sync-tests or skipping at all (also crash)
- looking for missing dlls (for Screen.mexw64)
- VBLSyncTest and PerceptualVBLSyncTest look fine and have results (for me)

It has to be either something very simple, or very specific - I'm somehow out of ideas. My guess would be that the Radeon vertical sync on setting does not work - for what reason ever.

ANY guesses, tips are apreciated. (even other ways to test Screen or vertical sync in Matlab/Psychtoolbox)

Comment: maybe to delete, since quite specific, maybe(?) not solvable with code and my angriness caused by days of wasted time!

Answer (score 1):

after hours of search, I think I've found a solution - oh Windows! (and oh, one simple line of code)

`Screen('Preference', 'ConserveVRAM', 4096);`

> **4096 == kPsychUseBeampositionQueryWorkaround**
>   Tell PTB to always use the workaround for broken beamposition queries in
>   VBL on MS-Windows, even if the automatic startup test does not detect any
>   problems. This for rare cases where the test fails to detect broken
>   setups. [[Psychtoolbox Docs]](http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/ConserveVRAMSettings)

I will do a recheck after some Videocache action and restarts.

---

**edit:**
well, that did only work once, and randomly a second time - it seems like the ATI Radeon driver behave not quite deterministically - I also checked on a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04.1). Specifically, the VSync rate seems to behave somehow strangely.

It generally works on that specified Linux with the open source `radeon` drivers (instead of the `fglrx` ones) though. -> The Problem on that Linux system: it can only be configured as one Screen (two monitor setup would be nice for debug on one Screen). (Yes, I've tried: Unity, Gnome, Xmonad, Gnome+Xmonad - but I guess that is another story)

Alright, I've written enough, my solution: use a Linux distro (quite unsatisfying though, as I could not accomplish for everything to work).

Comment: restart of matlab and it crashes again.. why, WHY! (all I did was trying out some of the `ConserveVRAM` options)